# Setting name property of control in code-behind causes errors

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

My current code is as follows:

```
           MyControl pvc = new MyControl ( );
           pvc.SetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty, "Control_Name");

           try
           {
              Grid.SetColumn( pvc, c );
              Grid.SetRow( pvc, r );
              layoutRoot.Children.Add( pvc );
           }
           catch( Exception excep )
           {
              System.Windows.MessageBox.Show( excep.ToString( ) );
           }
```

My issue is that I get an exception on the line I try to add the control to the layout (layoutRoot.Children.Add) and this exception only happens if I tried setting the nameproperty of the control, if I don't it works fine.

The exception is a 'System.ArgumentException: Value does not fal within expected range(...)

All i'm really trying to do is set the Name property of the control in codebehind instead of XAML (using x:Name="name"0

edit: The full exception is:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does
>   not fall within the expected range. at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32
>   hr) at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_Addvalue[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection'1Collection,
>   CValue value) at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_AddDependencyObject[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection'1
>   collection, DependencyObject value) at
>   System.Windows.PresentationFrameworlCollection'1.AddDependencyObject(DependencyObject value) at
>   System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.AddInternal(UIElement
>   value) at
>   System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection'1.Add(T
>   value) at
>   Controls.MyControl.CreateLayout()

Comment: just added the entire error message...

Comment: Does it happen for all values or only specific ones?

Comment: @meds: Out of interest, why are you setting the names at all? They are normally only useful to Visual Studio (in generating the designer files).

Comment: @HiTech Magic I plan on retrieving them later and using their names seems like the best way to do it, that way I can give each a unique name....

Comment: @meds: Better off adding your own attached property to hold "whatever you like". That's the sort of thing attached properties are designed for whereas the name property has an existing purpose.

Comment: @HiTech Magic What's the purpouse of the name property then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I was setting the same name multiple times, in hindsight that was a rather dumb thing to do on my part.